# Entity Framework, Repository pattern, wrong method of dbContext create?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, dbcontext

I use simply repository pattern. BaseRepository is base abstract class for all repository classes, it create and dispose dbContext. Is seems that everything is working ok but during code analysing Virtual Studio give me a warning:

> CA2214    Do not call overridable methods in
>   constructors  'BaseRepository.BaseRepository(string,
>   ApplicationDbContext)' contains a call chain that results in a call to
>   a virtual method defined by the class.

I create the new object of ApplicationDbContext (this class directly inherit from IdentityDbContext) in constructor. 
Is a bad practise? I don't want to override Dispose in any extending class (but it have to be virtual because in the other way VS says that I implemented IDisposable incorrectly). 
If it is wrong how I can do it in a better way with all profits that create dbcontext in constructor gives (easy testing with no default context, no need create context in all repo methods, etc.)?

It is my code:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository : IDisposable
{
    protected ApplicationDbContext context { get; private set; }
    protected String userName;

    protected BaseRepository(string userName, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        if(userName != null)
             this.userName = userName;
        else{
             Dispose(); //that is unnecessary and stupid piece of code
             throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    protected BaseRepository(string userName) : this(userName, new ApplicationDbContext()) { }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### edited 20.03.2015

Sorry my fault, I have in constructor function with can call Dispose() function (I tried have simple code and I not write it here). Sorry again, I promise that I will never cut again my code "for simple" in that stupid way. Thanks everybody for help and your time.

Comment: `BaseRepository.BaseRepository(string, ApplicationDbContext)` There is no such a overloaded version of constructor in your baserepository class!

Comment: Sorry my fault, for simpler code I remove first argument from my constructors (but I forgot remove it from warning). Although maybe it is important (i don't think so but maybe) so I update my code (now constructor args looks like in my app)

Comment: In order to make a code simple you just removed a part of code that was much important to the question warning says ** Do not call overridable methods in constructors 'BaseRepository.BaseRepository(string, ApplicationDbContext)'** and in your example there is no such a code.

Comment: Yes you have right, sorry again. Thanks for your replies and time with your spent on my problem.

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx)? What in the documentation was unclear? `IDispose` does not require the method to be virtual. Where did you get that requirement from? How to do it a better way? - Don't call virtual methods in your constructor.

Comment: chill, if you not make virtual method Dispose(bool disposing) during code analyze VS give you a warning that you should do it.

"Don't call virtual methods in your constructor." - yea that is the point of this topic and thing with I learn here

Answer (score 0):

You can not call the protected constructor, which takes a parameter from the class itself. Protected methods can only be called from classes derived classes.

Comment: thanks for reply, but you not have right, protected constructors are for derived classes and for the class itself (like other protected methods)